# Expo StatusBar whitespace

Tags: android, react-native, expo

On expo I experienced a whitespace problem after upgrading to expo 38.

The problem only occurred on android. It caused the StatusBar to not display as well.

[image: Expo android whitespace on Top]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Use `expo-status-bar` as opposed to StatusBar found in `react-native`